# How to use single global variable for multiple Python files

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a small game in python and I have created 3 python files:

1st file **vars.py**  is intended to store global variables. Let's say it contains single variable and nothing else:

```
runGame = True
```

2nd file **my_events.py** should handle game events and is using **vars.py**.

```
from vars import *

def game_events():

    global runGame
    runGame = False
```

3rd file **myGame.py** is a main game file. It contains main game loop and uses variable from **vars.py** as well:

```
#I am using this form of import to make it easier to refer to runGame variable
from vars import *
from my_events import game_events

def game_loop():

    global runGame
    while runGame:
        game_events()

game_loop()
quit()
```

I would assume that when I run **myGame.py** the program ends as the value of *runGame* variable is changed to False during first *game_loop()* cycle when the *game_events()* is called. But it seems the *runGame* in **myGame.py** is not the same that the *runGame* in **my_events.py**. So how do I make a variable that is global to all 3 files and when its value changes it affects them all? Or is this a totally wrong approach? (I read that global variables are evil but I don't know how to avoid them in some cases.)

Comment: A simple way to avoid this is to pass the relevant state to the functions that need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to avoid overwriting the variable name with a new value. You can do this by importing the *module* instead of the *variable*.

```
import vars as v
v.runGame = False
```

If you tweak your code to exclusively modify and access the `runGame` variable like this, you'll get the "global variable" behavior you'd expect. Otherwise, when you do the assignment in file 1, you're only overwriting what the name `runGame` means in that file, not what the original variable is.